# Correct modulus in Montgomery reduction

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand Montgomery reduction from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) (the algorithm matches in the original paper). For the reduction algorithm, the modular inverse of $R$ wrt. $N$ is calculated as $R^{-1}$. An N' is calculated from equation $R.R^{-1} - NN'$ such that $NN' = R.R^{-1} - 1$.
Now in the reduction algorithm in section ["The REDC algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication#The_REDC_algorithm), $m$ and $t$ are computed as
m ← ((T mod R)N′) mod R
t ← (T + mN) / R

The m is expanded to be $TNN'$ and since $T.NN'$ becomes $T(R.R^{-1} - 1)$.

But how can this be done since m is calculated modulo R but $NN' = R.R^{-1} - 1$ holds true for modulo N?

Comment: I'd give you a simpler way for their examples, prior to that but it's not the answer relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

> The m is expanded to be $TNN'$ and since $T.NN'$ becomes $T(R.R^{-1} - 1)$.

No, in the correctness proof we use only that $m\equiv TNN'\pmod R$ and the latter holds because  $T\equiv (T\mod R) \pmod R $ and $(TN’\mod R) \equiv TN’ \pmod R$. Next, since   $RR’-NN’=1$, we have $NN’\equiv –1\pmod R$ and finally we obtain $T+mN\equiv 0\pmod R$.