# How to perform Montgomery reduction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Trying to understand the theory behind Montgomery multiplication.  My number theory is not advanced enough to get through Montgomery's original paper.

Referring back to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187986/correct-modulus-in-montgomery-reduction), which in turn refers back to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication):

The article uses $N=17, R=100 \;\; (\text{gcd}(17,100) = 1)$ for modulus and multiplier.
The article states that "the extended Euclidean algorithm efficiently determines integers $R', N'$ that satisfy Bézout's identity", in this case, $RR' + NN'=1$.
Since $R,N$ are coprime here, $R'$ is the modular inverse of $R \bmod N$ and $N'$ is the modular inverse of $N \bmod R$.
Using the EEA, a pair of coefficients for these values is 8, -47: 8*100 + (-47)*17 = 1.

But the article then states that $RR'- NN'=1$  (not $RR'\textbf{+}NN=1'$).
So $N'$ here would be the **negative** of the modular inverse, or +47.
The intent is clear in the worked example further down, where $N'= 47$ is used.

Is this simply a confusing choice of variable notation or am I missing something?